# Is Lightning Linting available OOB in any IDE like Mavesmate or Force.com ide

Tags: mavensmate, force.com-ide

Just like we can see suggestions or errors while typing code in eclipse. Is there any linting service available as per now for Lightning development in IDE.

I know, how we can use linting chrome extension in Salesforce Dev console.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lightning-linter-chrome/mcpnifepmgbbebcocfdpghgloaaklgjj

But do any IDE supports it?

Answer (score 1):

Under the hood, all linting is done via the [Salesforce.com Lightning CLI Tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/cli_intro.htm)

It is not supported in the current version of Force.com IDE. The new version of Force.com IDE that is stipulated to launch as part of SalesforceDX brings in a lot of command line flexibility so it will be interesting to see if it does support Salesforce Lightning CLI.

Dave Caroll wrote a neat Sublime plugin which provides linting support - you can check it out [here](https://github.com/dcarroll/sublime-lightning)